# YouTube iFrame API .seekTo() not a method?

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I know that .seekTo() works in the Javascript API, but I'm not able to get it working with the **iFrame** API. Is this method supported? The code below successfully embeds the video and successfully console.log-s the player object. I get the error "player.seekTo is not a function" in the console.

```
    <script>
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        var player;
        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw'
            });
        }
        $(window).load(function(){
            jQuery('#test').click(function(){
                //console.log('test');
                console.log(player);
                player.seekTo(25);
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <a href="#" id="test">Test</a>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here's [an updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RQK3/68/) using the new iframe api that works

FYI: If you're just using an iframe pure HTML embed you can put `?start=30` for the start time

```
<iframe width="640" height="390" 
        src="//www.youtube.com/embed/p2H5YVfZVFw?start=30" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

For the API you can start a video at a certain time like this.
Use the `start` parameter

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
     player = new YT.Player('player', {
       height: '390',
       width: '640',
       videoId: 'p2H5YVfZVFw',
         playerVars: { 'start': 159, 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1 },
       events: {
         'onReady': onPlayerReady,
         'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
       }

     });
```

You can only call `seekTo` after the player has started playing or it doesn't do anything. Check the `playerStateChange` callback :

```
onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
```

Add this callback function

```
function onPlayerStateChange(evt) 
{       
    if (evt.data==1) 
    {
        // this will seek to a certain point when video starts
        // but you're better off using 'start' parameter
        // player.seekTo(22);   
    }
}
```

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RQK3/68/) has buttons at the bottom to seek to 30, 60, 90 seconds. It has been tested with all browsers that rhyme with 'rome'. When it opens it puts up an alert box for the `player.seekTo` function type. If this shows 'undefined' you have a problem.

Comment: @rogerdpack does youtube work normally? Do you have any other YouTube code on your page. I’m not sure how you’d get that error using this.

Comment: Yes, normal youtube works.  Maybe it's a video only you can view?

Answer (score 3):

This works as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/JbwY4/ (FF 11, Chrome 17).

Make sure that the following conditions are satisfied:

1. A container with ID `player` is defined: `<div id="player"></div>`.
2. The code is **not deferred**. Ie, not within an `onload` event, `$(document).ready`, `setTimeout`, etc. Otherwise, the IFrame API fails to load, and the code will not work.
3. jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Are you saying that when you click the #test link, the video seeks as intended (because your snippet did not for me)? I'm not having any problem embedding the video, I'm having trouble making the seekTo() function work.

Comment: I tried it in FF and Safari, and it worked. For some reason Chrome on OSX isn't doing anything when I click the #test link. The console is giving me the same "player.seekTo is not a function" error.

Comment: @thechrisvoth I went through the hassle of creating a OSX VM (OS X Lion), installed Chrome 18.0.1025.142. Although the video does not play well (Mac / Flash / Chrome bug?), the `player.seekTo` method **does** work.

Answer (score 1):

The `seekTo()` method is only available after the `onReady` event.

Here is an example that starts playing at 100s:

http://jsfiddle.net/9RQK3/

Comment: What browser do you use? I tested it in FF and Chrome and it worked.

Comment: I tried it in FF and Safari, and it worked. For some reason Chrome on OSX isn't seeking.

Comment: chrome on os x seeking for me

Answer (score 0):

i belive not all of the javascript methods have been implimented yet on the iframe api as its experimental so i'd guess not if you tried it and it failed. However i haven't used the iframe api in detail.