# My Youtube player is not worked?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have add a youtube video on my page through this code.

```
 <div id="ytplayer"></div>
            <script>
                // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
                var tag = document.createElement('script');
                tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
                var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
                // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
                var player;
                function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
                        height: '390',
                        width: '640',
                        videoId: 'o9UQSUHHdtA',
                        events: {
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
```

I play the video when user click on button. it's come visible by remove display:none. now it's not worked in Firefox, work fine in chrome. Can someone help me on it.

Thanks: live is [here](http://freelancehood.com/test121/).

it's show me `TypeError: player.seekTo is not a function` Do someone know how to wait for load the player. if I do player.seekTo manually in firebug then it's worked.

Comment: Have you any error message in your FF console?

Answer (score 0):

[YouTube iFrame API .seekTo() not a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813774/youtube-iframe-api-seekto-not-a-method#answer-9829679)

Make sure that the following conditions are satisfied:

> 1. A container with ID player is defined: `<div id="ytplayer"></div>.`
> 2. The code is not deferred. Ie, not within an onload event, $(document).ready, setTimeout, etc. Otherwise, the IFrame API fails to load, and the code will not work.
> 3. jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Pranav, The problem is I want to show my div from hidden to visible state. this thing in Firefox not make me able to seeTo(0) (starting point) for the video. it's because YT not ready in Firefox when it's hide. in Chrome I can see the hidden video can be played but not in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'o9UQSUHHdtA',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I already write it but It's loaded when it's hide. this is unsual for me. only statechange work for me that I have used. Try my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
var _isPlayerReady=  false;
     function _playVideo(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                        if (_isPlayerReady) {
                            player.seekTo(0);
                        }
                        else{
                            _playVideo();
                        }
                },1000);
            }

function onPlayerReady(event){
isPlayerReady = true;
}
```

As Ciack404 tell their is 2 event available In YT API. here is how I make it.

I call onPlayerReady on ready event. because it's hide then this not make it usable in Firefox (if you not tried to use Show() callback then this trick useful).

this code call check player exist and play the video on next second when it's worked. this work fine in every browser.

Note:- I have seen a hidden div video can be played in Chrome but not work in Firefox 17 (For now).This is why I setTimeout feature because my video come to visible state from hidden.