# new YT.Player() working in development but not production

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api, production-environment, youtube-iframe-api

It seems that `new YT.Player()` is working in development but not production.

```
var player = new YT.Player(domId, {
  events: {
    onReady: function() {
      // because of a bug in the youtube iframe api
      var p;
      player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
        if (e.data === 1) {
          p = $interval(function() {
            var elapsedTime = Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime());
            $scope.skim.sections[len-1].startTime = elapsedTime;
            setHMS($scope.skim.sections[len-1], elapsedTime);
          }, 1000);
        }
        else {
          $interval.cancel(p);
        }
      });
      console.log("onReady fired");
      updateStartTimeAndSeekTo($scope.skim.sections[len-1]);
      player.pauseVideo();
    }
  }
});
```

This code is supposed to update some input fields when the video plays. It does this in development, but not production.

[This](https://skimmablevideos.herokuapp.com/skims/new) is the live page. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaRZ4GpOFBc&feature=youtube_gdata_player) is a video explaining how it is supposed to work. And [this](https://github.com/adamzerner/skimmableVideos/blob/master/client/app/skims/new/new.controller.js) is the relevant GitHub code.

I really don't know how to debug this.

- For some reason the `console.log()` statements don't seem to be appearing in production. Without those I don't know what to do.
- I checked the network tab and it seems that the api code is being downloaded successfully.
- And `heroku logs` shows no errors.

Comment: I believe https://github.com/adamzerner/skimmableVideos/blob/master/client/app/skims/new/new.controller.js#L275 line of code causing problem

Comment: @pankajparkar right, `player` is undefined and I think it's because `new YT.Player()` isn't working. I don't know why `new YT.Player()` isn't working though.

Comment: player is defined. it has values. but the seekTo method inside player is missing. is it YT.Player() API method or you missed to write it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813774/youtube-iframe-api-seekto-not-a-method some what related to seekTo issue..

Comment: How do you know that player is defined (I'm not doubting it, just want to know how to figure that out myself). I'm not sure what you're asking about `YT.Player()`, but it works perfectly in development so I don't think I'm using it wrong (unless somehow it requires different use in production, which I didn't see anything about in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)).

Comment: I'm having screenshot taken from chrome debugger how can i show you..?

Comment: By posting the screenshot in the comments

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/users/PankajParkar/folders/Default/media/5e717802-93be-4c34-bed1-e46c44d7d016

in screen shot b is nothing but player object.In that only seekTo method is missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67679/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-adam-zerner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
<iframe style="height: 156.443444006753px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3eMA0GvpXl0?showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http://localhost:9000" ng-class="{ 'unloadedFrame': !skim.videoUrl }" class="subsection-iframe" responsive-height="" resize-on-load="" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" ng-src="skim.embedUrl" id="subsection-0-0"></iframe>
```

Check the iframe source url contain `origin=http://localhost:9000` hardcoded. If you removed the origin parameter from url. It started working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in the production environment config file. Adding 
`config.assets.debug = true` to production.rb fixed it for me.