# How to aply a Youtube API method to a selected <iframe> element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have embeded many Youtube videos that are created with a react-player component, so I can't find a way to aply the iframe api methods as are described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) like this:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div id="player"></div>
    <button onclick={stopVideo}>Stop</button>

    <script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        });
      }

      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I'm trying to aply directly on the iframe element with something like this:

```
video = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
video.pauseVideo()
```

Here is the full component:

```
const Slider = (props) => {
  const [sliders, setSliders] = useState([])
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

  //stop and play when change selected video in Carousel
  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    let beforeSlide = sliders[index]
    let afterSlide = sliders[selectedIndex]
    let video

    if (beforeSlide.type_rsc == 1) {
      if (beforeSlide.resource.indexOf('youtube')) {
        video = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
        console.log(video.getPlayerState())
        video.pauseVideo()
      }
    }
    if (afterSlide.type_rsc == 1) {
      if (beforeSlide.resource.indexOf('youtube')) {
        video = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1]
        video.playVideo()
      }
    }
    setIndex(selectedIndex)
  }
  //loads Youtube API
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.YT) {
      const tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';

      const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    } 
  }, [])
  //get videos which will be embedded
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getSlidersClient() {
      const rs = await slidersClient()
      if (rs.status === 200) {
        setSliders(rs.data)
      }
    }
    getSlidersClient()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {sliders.length > 0 ? (
        <Container className="container-slider margin-top-md">
          <Carousel
            controls={true}
            activeIndex={index}
            onSelect={handleSelect}
          >
            {sliders.map((item, i) => (
              <Carousel.Item key={i}>
                <ReactPlayer
                controls={true}
                id={i + item.resource}
                url={item.resource}
                />
              </Carousel.Item>
            ))}
          </Carousel>
        </Container>
      ) : null}
    </>
  )
}
export default Slider
```

I recieve this error when I try to aply any API method:
TypeError: video.getPlayerState is not a function
but they are functions indeed as is mentioned in the documentation or in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813774/youtube-iframe-api-seekto-not-a-method) answer, so the error is caused for other reason evidently.

Is there a way to aply the youtube API methods selecting the element itself or how could be this achieved?

Comment: what is the error you are getting.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier this error gives me
TypeError: video.getPlayerState is not a function. The same with any method.

Comment: in the link provided by you, the methods playVideo and pauseVideo is only available on the player object (instance of YT.Player). Yet you are calling it on the video object which is just a reference of the iframe DOM element.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier I think you are on the right way with that you say. The trouble here is that I don't have a player object as the iframe is generated by the react-player component instead an instance of YT.Player generated in the component itself. I would love to know how aply the iframe API methods in a case like this.